# Java Multiple Root Tags Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

```
<manifest android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" package="com.sveder.hwopengl" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

```
<activity android:name="com.sveder.hwopengl.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape">


<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

It says "Multiple Root Tags" and there is only one root layout
thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the intent-filter and then close the manifest tag. So add `</intent-filter>` then `</manifest>` to the file.

Comment: You have not formatted the code that you pasted in correctly. Edit your post, highlight all of the xml, and use the editor to format it as code. Right now it is not displaying correctly on StackOverflow.